# How to break the axis in matlab

Tags: matlab

How could one break the `x` axis in the same figure (not the subplot function)?

You can see an example in line graph in panel b in the following picture, one single row data have been split into three parts as well as the `x` axis.
the question is how this plot can be achieved in matlab.

[image]

(like the **panel b** in this figure)

Comment: It is very unclear what you are after. What "red arrow"? Are you just asking how to make gaps appear in the axis as in figure e in your image?

Comment: yes, something like that(I haven't noticed that i have changed the posted picture...)

Comment: @rayryeng That gif should be part of SO comments by default.

Comment: Xin, plese, reformulate your question. It looks that you have an interesting problem here, but it is very difficult to understand what you want right now.

Comment: i make some updates, hope you can understand my description~
thank you!!!

Comment: What plotting functions do you use? `surf`? `imshow`? Any specific one that you want or any would do?

Comment: @AnderBiguri - lol thanks.  Someone didn't agree and removed it from the comments... but here it is for your benefit: http://img.pandawhale.com/post-37094-Tom-Cruise-WHAT-gif-Oblivion-I-wDog.gif

Answer (score 1):

Ill leave you an exmaple here using `surf`.

The trick is inserting `nan`s wherever you want the lines to appear "empty"

```
z=peaks(100);

% If you want to delete a certain amount of rows/cols
z2=z;
z2(:,10:15)=NaN;
z2(:,50:55)=NaN;
z2(:,75:80)=NaN;

% If you want to separate you data without deleting anything

z3=z;

z3=[z3(:,1:15) nan(size(z3,1),5) z3(:,16:75) nan(size(z3,1),5) z3(:,75:100) ];


% This last bit is only for plotting, so you can try it in your computer 
subplot(131)
title('Original')
surf(z,'edgecolor','interp')
axis off
view(2)
axis equal
subplot(132)
title('Deleted columns')
surf(z2,'edgecolor','interp')
axis off
view(2)
axis equal
subplot(133)
title('Separatedd data')
surf(z3,'edgecolor','interp')
axis off
view(2)

axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for you patience and and answers, but it seems not what i want~

Comment: the gray line in panel b is post-added, not the segment space~

Comment: @XIN I didnt add any gray line, as you didnt ask for the gray lines....Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: @XIN If you are trying this in your computer, you may see the lines gray, but that's just the background colour of the plot. There are no gray lines

Comment: @XIN If the snwer ws usefull, please consider accepting it. Else I can try to improve it if you give me more iformation

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of utilities on the File Exchange that allow you to do that:

- [Break X Axis](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42905-break-x-axis)
- [BreakXAxis](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3683-breakxaxis)

Comment: thanks, the latter one seems like what i expect, by any chance do you know some way to totally split it up like what they have done in the figure? like the line plot in panel B~

Comment: No, but the code is there for you to customise and adapt to your needs.